# PHP - Loop through multiple tables and populate a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I need to loop through multiple tables in my database and then populate multidimensional arrays with their contents. The code I have at the moment is returning a MySQL error. I've tried searching around but everything I find does not match my needs.

**Code**

```
// The arrays that will hold the data we wish to collect
$ids = array();
$data = array();

// The database tables we want to search through
$databaseTables = array("table1", "table2", "table3", "table4");

for ($x = 0; $x < 4; $x++) {
    // Create a new array for this table's data
    $ids[] = array();
    $data[] = array();

    // Query the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM '$databaseTables[$x]'";
    $result = @mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Collect the data
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $ids[$x][] = $row['id'];
        $data[$x][] = $row['data'];
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

**Edit**

The MySQL Error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table1'' at line 1

Comment: what is the mysql error being returned?

Comment: Edited the post with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont quote table names, use the backtick instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$databaseTables[$x]`";
```

If you have the mode `ANSI_QUOTES` turned on you can double quote table names as that causes quotes to be identifier quote characters (vs a string quote character), but by default this is not set.

Sources:

1. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html
2. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html
3. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

As an aside, I would advise you to not use the `mysql_*` functions any longer. They are deprecated and *will be removed* in future versions of PHP. See the [introduction page](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to mysql.

Instead, I would use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this answer when it lets me in a few minutes.

Comment: Don't do this at all: `$query = "SELECT * FROM '$databaseTables[$x]'";`, properly concatenate variables with a dot: `$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $databaseTables[$x];`

Comment: Why? When using double quotes you can use curly brackets `{}` and this is much cleaner than concatenating with a dot.

Comment: @smcjones Interpolating variables inside of double quoted strings like that used to bring about a performance penalty. I don't think that is the case anymore, or at least it's not as big as it used to be

Comment: @watcher Fair enough. My opinion is that the performance penalty is small, memory is cheap, and the biggest bottleneck for a PHP application is rarely the code. I understand the drive for efficiency but speed and ease of reading can also be important. If I were to eliminate inefficiencies in PHP it would be in looping and using wasteful functions. If I wanted to eliminate all inefficiencies, I would probably choose a different language.

Answer (score 1):

You are using single quotes. In MySQL you need to use back-ticks. You can also generally leave back-ticks out so long as you do not anticipate any conflicts via a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Further, if you have `or die` at the end you really don't need the `@` error suppressor. MySQL functions don't print out errors but if you add `or die` at the end you probably want to see what happens. Either remove `or die` or remove the `@` error suppressor.